# Why crash when I set CGFloat value to AssociatedObject by assign policy In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, assign

```
static var testValue = 1
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &testValue, 10.1, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &testValue)
```

When I execute the third line of code, it will crash , But when I change the value that I want to set to **10(or 10.0)**, it can successfully get the value. Why this happen?

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve? Your code uses the address of `testValue` only as the key for the associated object, the value is irrelevant and not used at all.

Comment: When I excute these code , it will crash! I wonder why crash? When I change the value from 10.1 to 10(or 10.0), it wont crash.

Answer (score 0):

Associated values store pointer sized items (typically eight bytes). When you try to read it, it will read a pointer sized item and overwrite eight bytes of memory. If the variable you are using is four bytes only, then four bytes of random memory are overwritten, with all kinds of consequences.

Comment: The second argument `&testValue` is  the *key* for objc_get/setAssociatedObject, the getter does not write to the memory at that address. Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: But Double value is eight bytes, when I store a double type value as associated value by assign policy , its crash either! On the other hand, why 10.0 is OK, and 10.1 will crash!